# Запись текста в правильной кодировке

Tags: кодировка, cmd

Код внизу находит все файлы содержащие someString, на рабочем столе и **записывает названия файлов в текстовый файл**

```
findstr/m someString %userprofile%\Desktop\*.txt > result.txt
```

Но если **файлы в названии содержит русский текст** то в результате вместо него будет набор случайных символов

**Как это исправить?**

`chcp 1251` ничего не изменяет в результате

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('findstr/m someString %userprofile%\Desktop\*.txt') Do Set V=%%~I
chcp 1251
Echo !V! > result.txt
```